# How can I position a FloatingActionButton spanning two widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I trying to position a FloatingActionButton spanning two widget in flutter.

like this.

[image]

However, this is my app screen.

[image]

I can't **stack the button on the center of two widget.**

How can I solve my question :(? This is the sample code of my app. Thanks.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class UserProfileBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserProfileBody({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  Widget _buildUserProfilePhoto(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(
        maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: const Image(
        fit: BoxFit.contain,
        image: NetworkImage(defaultUserProfileImage),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        _buildUserProfilePhoto(context),
        Stack(
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.topRight,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
              ),
            ),
            Column(
              children: [
                ListTile(
                  title: const Text('the title'),
                  subtitle: const Text('the subtitle'),
                  onTap: () {},
                )
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can place image inside stack, in this case UI will be

```dart
class UserProfileBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserProfileBody({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final double imageHeight = constraints.maxHeight * .5;
      debugPrint(imageHeight.toString());
      return Column(
        children: [
          Stack(
            clipBehavior: Clip.none,
            children: [
              // image
              Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    height: imageHeight,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  )
                  // _buildUserProfilePhoto(context),
                  ),
              Positioned(
                top: imageHeight - (64 / 2), //64 is default fab size
                right: 24,
                child: FloatingActionButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                ),
              ),
              // Column(
              //   children: [
              //     ListTile(
              //       title: const Text('the title'),
              //       subtitle: const Text('the subtitle'),
              //       onTap: () {},
              //     )
              //   ],
              // )
            ],
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Play with

```dart
Positioned(
  top: imageHeight - (64 / 2), //64 is default fab size
  right: 24,
  child: FloatingActionButton(
```

**Solution 2:**

And if you like place image above stack

```dart
Positioned(
  top: -(64 / 2),
```

```dart
class UserProfileBody extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserProfileBody({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
      final double imageHeight = constraints.maxHeight * .5;
      debugPrint(imageHeight.toString());
      return Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: imageHeight,
            color: Colors.green,
          ),
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight - imageHeight,
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                Positioned(
                  top: -(64 / 2), //64 is default fab size
                  right: 24,
                  child: FloatingActionButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: const Icon(Icons.photo_camera),
                  ),
                ),
                Column(
                  children: [
                    ListTile(
                      title: const Text('the title'),
                      subtitle: const Text('the subtitle'),
                      onTap: () {},
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}
```

> Use `clipBehavior: Clip.none,` on stack

[image]

Comment: I knew the 'Positioned' function for the first time. It's amazing...! Your code perfectly solved my problem.  Thank you very much :)!

Comment: glad to help, you can also use align but need some calculation on Y axis.